# rails nested model forms has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Im using simple_form gem and i need to do a nested form but im having trouble here is some code:

i have two models:

Apiphones:

```
class Apiphone < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :key, :phone
  validates_presence_of :phone
  belongs_to :store
end
```

Stores:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :apiphone
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :apiphone
end
```

and in my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@group,@store] do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :apiphone do |ph| %>
      <%= ph.input :phone %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but nothing is showing, any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

using `fields_for` in conjunction with `accepts_nested_attributes` assumes that the records are initialized.  This means that, using your models, `@store.apiphone` should not be `nil` when the form is generated.  The way to solve this issue is making sure that `apiphone` is initialized and associated to `@store` (both new and edit actions).

```
def new
  @store = Store.new
  @store.build_apiphone
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! confused me for long time

Answer (score 3):

I think you forget build apiphone in your controller, for example:

```
def new
 ...
 @store.build_apiphone
 ...
end
```

Comment: i'm not sure about this but `.build` is used for `has_many`. since this is a `has_one`, you need to use `build_apiphone`